# What's the definition of $x^g$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-rings

My question is really simple. I'm studying a book of group rings which doesn't define what is $x^g$, where $x,g$ are elements of the group $G$:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It is the same as $gxg^{-1}$.

Comment: I've also seen it used to denote $g^{-1}xg$, and is the image of $x$ under conjugation by $g$.

Comment: In this case either denotation works.

Comment: Since $(g,x) \mapsto x^g$ is a right action, $x^g = g^{-1} x g$ is correct since then $x^{gh} = (x^g)^h$.